# How can I rerun a while loop after exiting?

Tags: java, while-loop

I have the following code:
How can I run the while loop again after exiting? The reason is, after a game of tictactoe has finished, I exit the while loop. This is when I ask the user if they want to play again. If the user types in "y", I would like to return to the beginning of the while loop.
Thanks in advance.

```
        while(game.getGameState()!=GameState.XWIN &&
                game.getGameState()!=GameState.OWIN &&
                game.getGameState()!=GameState.DRAW ) {

            players[0].play(game);
            if(game.getGameState()!=GameState.XWIN) {
                players[1].play(game);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Need to have this code in another loop

Comment: By putting the stuff into a function and calling it every time you need it.

Comment: Make a larger while loop outside this one. The code to request another game is at the end of that larger while loop.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to nest your current **while** loop in an outer **while** loop, for example:

```
boolean quit = false;
while (!quit) {
    // Start Game....

    while(game.getGameState()!=GameState.XWIN &&
            game.getGameState()!=GameState.OWIN &&
            game.getGameState()!=GameState.DRAW ) {

        players[0].play(game);
        if(game.getGameState()!=GameState.XWIN) {
            players[1].play(game);
        }
    }

    // Game finished, ask to play again.
    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to play again?", 
            "Play Again?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if (result != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        quit = true; // if Yes is not selected then quit.
    }
}
```